# spring-social-linkedin compatibility with spring-social 1.1

Tags: spring-social-linkedin

We have a project which uses spring-social-facebook, spring-social-twitter, spring-social-linkedin and spring-social-google. We currently use the following versions:

- spring-social-core: 1.0.3
- spring-social-facebook: 1.0.1
- spring-social-twitter: 1.0.5
- spring-social-google: 1.0.0
- spring-social-linkedin: 1.0.0.RC1

We are attempting to update Facebook and Twitter to 1.1 There are no 1.1 libraries available for LinkedIn and Google+ at present, so the resulting versions are:

- spring-social-core: 1.1.0.RELEASE
- spring-social-facebook: 1.1.1.RELEASE
- spring-social-twitter: 1.1.0.RELEASE
- spring-social-google: 1.0.0
- spring-social-linkedin: 1.0.0.RC1

Since making this change, LinkedIn login no longer works, throwing the following exception:

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException'.
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class org.springframework.social.linkedin.api.LinkedInProfile]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
>    at [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@7659b0e8; line: 2, column: 3]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class org.springframework.social.linkedin.api.LinkedInProfile]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
>    at [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@7659b0e8; line: 2, column: 3]
>       at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:170) ~[spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:162) ~[spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:94) ~[spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:492) ~[spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:447) ~[spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.social.linkedin.api.impl.ProfileTemplate.getUserProfile(ProfileTemplate.java:79) ~[spring-social-linkedin-1.0.0.RC1.jar:na]
>       at com.globaldawn.social.core.oauth.handler.LinkedInOAuthHandler.authenticate(LinkedInOAuthHandler.java:94) ~[social-core-4.0.4219.jar:na]
>       at com.globaldawn.social.core.oauth.service.SocialOAuthService.authenticateWithSocialNetwork(SocialOAuthService.java:371) ~[social-core-4.0.4219.jar:na]
>       at com.globaldawn.social.core.oauth.service.SocialOAuthService.authenticate(SocialOAuthService.java:160) ~[social-core-4.0.4219.jar:na]
>       at com.globaldawn.social.web.controller.login.SocialLoginControllerUtil.login(SocialLoginControllerUtil.java:194) ~[classes/:na]
>       at com.globaldawn.social.web.controller.login.SocialLoginControllerUtil.successfulLoginCallback(SocialLoginControllerUtil.java:117) ~[classes/:na]
>       at com.globaldawn.social.web.controller.login.LinkedInSocialLoginController.successfulOAuthLoginCallback(LinkedInSocialLoginController.java:126) ~[classes/:na]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219) ~[spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) ~[spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:746) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:687) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) [spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915) [spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811) [spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735) [social-rest-service.war:na]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796) [spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) [social-rest-service.war:na]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:698) [social-rest-service.war:na]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1506) [social-rest-service.war:na]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494) [social-rest-service.war:na]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) [spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1486) [social-rest-service.war:na]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503) [social-rest-service.war:na]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138) [social-rest-service.war:na]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:564) [social-rest-service.war:na]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:213) [social-rest-service.war:na]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1096) [social-rest-service.war:na]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:432) [social-rest-service.war:na]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:175) [social-rest-service.war:na]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1030) [social-rest-service.war:na]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136) [social-rest-service.war:na]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [social-rest-service.war:na]
>       at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:173) [social-rest-service.war:na]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [social-rest-service.war:na]
>       at com.globaldawn.application.monitoring.RequestMetricsHandler.handle(RequestMetricsHandler.java:98) [social-rest-service.war:na]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [social-rest-service.war:na]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445) [social-rest-service.war:na]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:268) [social-rest-service.war:na]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:229) [social-rest-service.war:na]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358) [social-rest-service.war:na]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601) [social-rest-service.war:na]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532) [social-rest-service.war:na]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_51]
>   Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class org.springframework.social.linkedin.api.LinkedInProfile]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
>    at [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@7659b0e8; line: 2, column: 3]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:164) ~[jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1078) ~[jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:268) ~[jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:124) ~[jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2993) ~[jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2158) ~[jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
>       at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:167) ~[spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
>       ... 58 common frames omitted

We use gradle for our dependency management, which always takes the highest version number where different versions of a package are required, so the dependency of spring-social-linkedin on spring-social-core 1.0.3 is forcibly 'upgraded' to 1.1.0. Is this compatible? Is it possible to use spring-social-linkedin in a project that uses version 1.1 of spring-social-facebook and/or spring-social-twitter?

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be that spring-social-core v1.1 is not compatible with spring-social-linkedin v1.0 - v1.0 uses org.codehaus.jackson for serialising JSON, whereas v1.1 uses com.fasterxml.jackson.core.

You cannot upgrade spring-social-facebook or spring-social-twitter to v1.1 if you need to use spring-social-linkedin within the same module.

Not exactly surprising, but we'll probably need to move away from spring-social altogether as a result, as we need some newer functionality and cannot uncouple the different social networks.